# Partial differentiation gone wrong

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am trying to understand this equation given [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-pytorch-with-an-example-a-step-by-step-tutorial-81fc5f8c4e8e) to calculate Mean squared loss.

$$ \frac{\text{d}MSE}{\text{d}a} = \frac{\text{d}MSE}{\text{d}y} . \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}a} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N 2(y - a -bx) . (-1) $$

Doing partial diff following the product chain rule, Here are the steps I took
$$ \tag{1} \frac{\text{d}MSE}{\text{d}a} = \frac{\text{d}MSE}{\text{d}y} . \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}a}$$

$$ \tag{2} \frac{\text{d}MSE}{\text{d}y} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N 2(y - a - bx) $$

The third partial diff should be (I am not sure about it)

$$ \tag{3} \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}a} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N 2(-1) $$

Any suggestion where did I go wrong

Comment: Don't post images of equations. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Most people aren't going to bother looking through the links you've attached. I suggest you type the maths part of your question yourself using Latex [(see here for help)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @5xum I have updated the equations

Answer (score 1):

The link is rather incompletely written, and even more incompletely reproduced in the question. There is some Einstein sum convention used but not mentioned, the assignment of inner derivatives is not clear,...

You get
$$
MSE = \sum_{i=1}^N(y_i-\hat y_i)^2\implies \frac{∂ MSE}{∂\hat y_i}=2(y_i-\hat y_i)(-1)=2(\hat y_i-y_i)
$$
as you have a square of a difference, and the "active" variable is the second term.
Then
$$
\hat y_i=a+bx_i\implies \frac{∂\hat y_i}{∂a}=1~~\land ~~\frac{∂\hat y_i}{∂b}=x_i
$$
Then in combination, the intermediate variable in the cited chain rule is the full vector $\bf \hat y$ of all the $\hat y_i$,
$$
\frac{∂ MSE}{∂a}=\frac{∂ MSE}{∂\bf\hat y}\frac{∂\bf\hat y}{∂a}
=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{∂ MSE}{∂\hat y_i}\frac{∂\hat y_i}{∂a}
=\sum_{i=1}^N 2(a+bx_i-y_i)\cdot 1
=-2\sum_{i=1}^N (y_i-a-bx_i) ,
$$
$$
\frac{∂ MSE}{∂b}=\frac{∂ MSE}{∂\bf\hat y}\frac{∂\bf\hat y}{∂b}
=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{∂ MSE}{∂\hat y_i}\frac{∂\hat y_i}{∂b}
=\sum_{i=1}^N 2(a+bx_i-y_i)\cdot x_i
=-2\sum_{i=1}^N (y_i-a-bx_i) ⋅x_i
$$
etc.